# Django - Update a value in database on another table

Tags: python-3.x, django, filter, foreign-keys

I have two tables

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

An incoming value (data) is coming from a webhook `payment_confirmation(event.data.object.id)` containing the payment_id. I want this value to be matched with Payment.payment_id (Payment table) and then update Order.is_ordered=True (Order table).

How i can do that? I tried below with no success:

```
Order.objects.filter(payment__payment_id=data).update(is_ordered=True)
```

From the other hand I can update Payment.status successfully by running:

```
Payment.objects.filter(payment_id=data).update(status='COMPLETED')
```

Thank you

Comment: >> Check Order.objects.filter(payment__payment_id=data)                                                exist using django shell

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just

```
Order.objects.filter(payment_id=data).update(is_ordered=True)
```

You don't need to "payment__payment_id=data". Dajngo will fetch the payment_id easily.